# Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: r, xampp, shiny

I am on windows using Xampp
I want to upload a file on shiny, but I receive this error; Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
This is what I have in R:

```
mysql = list(
    "host" = "127.0.0.1",
    "port" = 3306,
    "user" = "myuser",
    "password" = "mypassword"
    “databaseName" = "xxx"),
```

Could someone tell me how to fix it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could create a user specially for your shiny application and give this user proper privileges. If you can access a terminal / MySQL workbench where you can type in SQL commands you could try:

Start by creating the user:

```
CREATE USER 'shinyuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password123';
```

The create the database if necessary:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase;
```

And finally give permission to the new user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON shinyuser.* TO 'MyDatabase'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises when your username and password is not matching with your database username and password. So please check your database username and password first then try it again.